# Что за формат запроса?

Tags: android, retrofit2

Подскажите что за формат запроса:

```
grant_type=password&client_id=2&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&username=example@example.com&password=password&scope=*,
```

Сейчас отправляю этим способом и получаю следующее:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@POST("oauth/token")
fun getUserAuthorizationToken(@Body userAuthorizationRequest: UserAuthorizationRequest): Observable<TokenResponse>
```

Где `userAuthorizationRequest`- Data Class:

```
data class UserAuthorizationRequest(
    val grant_type: String = "password",
    val client_id: Long = 2,
    val client_secret: String = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    val username: String? = null,
    val password: String? = null,
    val scope: String = "*"
)
```

Результат:

```
{"client_id":8,"client_secret":"vc3ZzOrNzRPf55Ebkgd6cyYnRHF8Jj0YgBN6v1lG","grant_type":"password","password":"Getdata1","scope":"*","username":"anton@anton.com"}
```

Пробовал еще вот таким вот вариантом, но он не отработал так, как мне нужно:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@POST("oauth/token")
fun getUserAuthorizationToken(
    @Field("client_id") clientId: Int,
    @Field("client_secret") clientSecret: String,
    @Field("grant_type") grantType: String,
    @Field("password") password: String,
    @Field("scope") scope: String,
    @Field("username") username: String
): Observable<TokenResponse>
```

Результат:

```
 client_id=8&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=password&password=Password1&scope=*&username=example%40example.com
```

Где я оступился, что я сделал не так? Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: А что не так со вторым вариантом - вроде всё верно?

Comment: @woesss Я видел ваш предыдущий комментарий, сервер отвечает некорректно. Бекендеру писать не хочу, думал сам разберусь. Второй вариант подходит? Просто допустим символ @ в моем варианте отображается не как @,  а как %40. Поэтому думал, что я некорректно отправляю данные

Comment: Так и должно быть - это особенность формы, значения кодируются в url-encoded формат. И при использовании аннотации `@FormUrlEncoded` заголовок `Content-Type:  application/x-www-form-urlencoded` указывать не обязательно. В удалённом комменте я неправильно понял про результат (подумал что это ответ сервера) - поэтому не всё сказанное верно.

Comment: @woesss Нет, все, что тут указано - это мои данные, которые я отправляю на сервер. Ответ от сервера добавлю в вопрос.

Comment: @woesss Все, я починил. Спасибо большое, за уделенное время и ответ! Проблема была в том, что мне бекендер дал SECRET_KEY неверный...